# How can I improve a polygon postgis query

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, postgis

I find a lot of example on google but many are old ...

My query but currently taking a long time to execute, I think it may be optimized: I am trying to find all the geog which are in 1 point polygon.

```
table restaurant ( name text,
 longitude float,
latitude float, geog geometry);
```

and:

```
CREATE INDEX if not exists idx_restaurant_geog ON restaurant USING gist (geog) ;
UPDATE restaurantSET geog = ST_Point(longitude,latitude);
```

So I converted the longitude and latitude to geometry.

here is the query I use to find all the restaurants that are present in a polygon:

```
select restaurant from poi where ST_Intersects(geog, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(:s_polygoneDepartement)) = 'true'


:s_polygoneDepartement: is parameter
```

thanking you

Comment: Are spatial indices added? Can you describe the tables? What does long time mean? How many records are you looking at? Did you analyze the query? Some useful comments to be found here https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1798

Comment: I have around 400,000 records. the time of the request is long = 4.5 seconds. I changed to this query, which takes 1.5 seconds, but I'm not sure if I can improve it further:  select * from restaurant where ST_DWithin(geog,ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(:s_polygoneDepartement), 4326) "

Comment: Are spatial indices added? That is to say ? I just converted the longitude and latitude to geometry and added an index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is just fine. Creating a `gist` index in the geometry column as you did is the standard procedure.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_poi_geom ON poi USING gist (geom);

SELECT name,geom FROM poi 
WHERE ST_Contains('POLYGON((...))',geom);
```

However, depending on the use case and data distribution you might wanna take a look at [`partial indexes`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) or even try to force a [`index only scan`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) using the `INCLUDE` clause in your index, so that the planner does not need to look for the data in the table. But again, it all depends on your use case.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7763d334e1b0d4979d681de3bb6af007)

Comment: Ok I will test because my request is too long for me (about 1 second). I try this weekend and you will keep in touch

Comment: @Camel4488 any luck with the index?

Comment: Hello, I'm starting my project again... And I don't know if I should stay on postgis or change to Mongodb knowing that my data sources are .json files

Comment: I don't know if with mongodb I can do the same type of queries as with postgis

Comment: @Camel4488 you should ask a new question, as it is a different issue. Also, it's been over a year and you didn't even accept this answer here. Some people might consider that before answering your questions again.

Comment: Sorry yes your answer was correct

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74768954/mongodb-vs-postgres-vs-postgis/74769042#74769042